# Accessing WSO2 API Manager portals using Load Balancer

Tags: wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

I'm using the WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0 docker image and deployed it in Azure Kubernetes using the HELM chart.

Everything is good and working if I access the application URLs using the DNS name assigned to the ingress IP address. For example https://internal.sp.com/publisher

But, when I come through the Azure Application gateway (a load balancer), all the management URLs (For example, https://external.sp.com/publisher) it’s throwing “requested resource not found” in the browser

Is there any specific setting that needs to be done when using the load balancer in front of the API Manager?

Comment: You need to have the external hostname in https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-1/wso2am-pattern-1-am-conf.yaml#L31

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have changed and deployed it. But now, when I try to access https://external.sp.com/carbon, it's redirecting to https://internal.sp.com in the browser, which it's supposed to be staying with https://external.sp.com/carbon. Any missing settings?

Comment: Should we be adding any rewrite rule at the load balancer level?

Comment: Once you changed the above config, this should work.

Comment: Not working. Just to let you know I'm using single instance helm chart for the installation. Should I be chaging the host name directly in wso2am-single-node-am-conf.yaml file or the values.yaml file?

Comment: Appreciate any advice

Comment: Both options work. So you can use any option here. Once you make the changes, make sure the api manager pod is restarted to apply the changes. Are you having this issue only with carbon console or does it work with the publisher and other portals?

Comment: I did restarted the pod and even I had installed the helm chart again. But still not working. Any other specific settings that I have to do with in wso2 api manager side? Or where can I find useful info on finding the root cause why it’s not working?

Comment: And none of the portals working. I’m getting requested resource not found error message

Comment: Probably now the requests are going to the APIM gateway and you get 404 from the API gateway. In the Azure application gateway, make sure that the requests are routed to the port 9443. All the portals are accessible via 9443 port and gateway is exposed via 8243.

Comment: I have ingress controller in between and when I checked the ingress ports it’s listening on. 443 and 80 and It is my understanding that based on the rules mentioned in the ingress services yaml files it’s going to route the traffic to the wso2 apim pods on ports 9443 and 8243. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: You want to use both the ingress controller and Azure application gateway?

Comment: Yes. It's because my ingress controller is private (only accessible in the internal network) in fact, my Azure Kubernetes services is deployed in the private cluster. So, I can access the application portals and gateway using the ingress controller DNS hostname(https://internal.sp.com) now I want to publish the same on the internet, so I have to use an external load balancer (in this case, its Azure Application Gateway) to access from internet via https://external.sp.com. Please let me know if this is supported architecture.

Comment: Basically, this is how the flow is going to be 
Client (Browser) --> Azure app Gateway --> Ingress Controller --> WSO2 APIM

Comment: Appreciate your response

Comment: Hi Pubci, Appreciate any response on this issue.

Comment: I found a simple solution and I think this will benefit some one out there with such architecture and hence posting - Configure ingress service with both ingress controller DNS name and Azure App gateway DNS name and then deploy the helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution and I think this will benefit some one out there with such architecture and hence posting - Configure ingress service with both ingress controller DNS name and Azure App gateway DNS name and then deploy the helm chart. Let me know if any one have any questions